Table too small for the page
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Comparison of Different Camera Types for Mobile Robots.} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c c p{50cm}|p{2cm}|}

\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\textbf{Camera Type} & \textbf{Application Time} & \textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Advantages and Disadvantages} \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
Monocular Camera & 2007 {[}70{]} & Contains only one lens, the basic unit of the visual sensor & Pros: easy to integrate, low cost. \newline Cons: cannot directly provide in-depth information. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Stereo Camera & 2008 {[}71{]} & Simultaneous generation of left and right images for stereoscopic visual & Pros: produces two images, can be used for stereo vision. \newline Cons: calibrates camera, computationally complex, limited depth estimation range. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
RGBD Camera & 2011 {[}72{]} & RGB images and depth images can be provided directly & Pros: provides accurate depth information. \newline Cons: depth information is susceptible to environmental influences. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Event Camera & 2017 {[}73{]} & Uses pixel changes as events, captures luminance changes with microsecond time resolution & Pros: copes with high dynamics, scenes with large lighting variations, low power consumption. \newline Cons: requires image pre-processing for traditional info. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
Light Field Camera & 2017 {[}74{]} & Adds microlens arrays to camera lenses to add scale information to monocular cameras & Pros: provides scale information for monocular cameras. \newline Cons: high computational volume, difficult to achieve real-time computing. \\ [0.5ex]
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}


Unless you have a very big page, it is unlikely that a table with a 50cm column will be readable.

Never do \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}  scaling tables in such a way makes it impossible to get consistent font sizes in the document. Remove the scaling and then specify column widths that are not half a metre wide and you will not need to scale.
